# Erlang: lots of case ... of

Tags: erlang

In erlang, I often write code like this:

```
case A of
    A1 ->
        something_simple_1;
    A2 ->
        case B of
            B1 ->
                something_simple_2;
            B2 ->
                case C of
                    C1 ->
                        something_simple_3;
                    C2 ->
                        ...
                end
        end
end
```

It's ugly, how can I avoid this?

Comment: You may find this answer a useful reference: "[IF Statement -- Nested Cases in Erlang](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28673437/erlang-nested-cases/28673997#28673997)". It discusses this in a general way at first, and then in the context of a specific problem the OP had (where the complete answer demonstrated that reasoning about the problem differently almost completely reduced the perceived need for a `case` to nothing).

Comment: Can you paste a real code example? There are lots of opportunities to use guards and top-level pattern matching in functions here if the makeup of A, B and C are known.

Answer (score 5):

```
case {A, B, C} of
    {A1, _, _} -> 
        something_simple_1;
    {A2, B1, _} ->
         something_simple_2;
    {A2, B2, C1} ->
         something_simple_3;
    {A2, B2, C2} ->
    ...
end
```

Note that this doesn't allow you to e.g. avoid calculation of `C` when you don't need it; more generally applicable approach is just to extract functions.